# What is collapse multiplier in OptumG2 software? How to reduce the error percentage for calculating active Earth pressure?

Tags: civil-engineering, design, retaining-wall

I am working on an analysis of a retaining wall. After doing a limit analysis on the structure, the collapse multiplier that I am getting for both upper and lower limit is very high. As it is not clearly mentioned whether it is load or stress, I continued my analysis considering it to be **stress**.

Using this value as stress and finding out the coefficient of active earth pressure for 30 degrees, the difference in this and the theoretical value is quite big.

I have gone through the manual, examples and videos that have been provided but still I am not getting my desired results.

Comment: What are “desired results”? The ones that give a cheap solution or the ones that hold the earth back?